# Aligning minipages with new margins

Tags: margins, minipage

I've extended the page margins using geometry, but when I create a minipage for  my headings the right aligned minipage aligns with the original margin. How can I make it so that it aligns with the new margin?

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}

%% Language %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
%Packages
\usepackage{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[showframe,right=2cm, left=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

\begin{figure}[t]
\flushright
\includegraphics[width=4.6cm]{D:/Documents/Pictures/logo.jpg}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{!}{.9cm} {General Rig Description}

\vspace{.5cm}
\Huge Superduper Land Rigs:\\
Rig 291

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7cm]{D:/Documents/Pictures/rig.JPG}  
\end{figure}
\textsc{Written By}\\
\huge
{Name Name}
\end{center}
\vspace {.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushleft
\Large
\textsc{Important title}\\
Name Name
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
\flushright
\Large
\textsc{Important title}\\
Name Name
\end{minipage}
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Can you sketch what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Use `\hfill` between the minipages:

```
\documentclass[titlepage,a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} %%For loading graphic files
\usepackage[showframe,right=2cm, left=2cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}       
\flushright
\includegraphics[width=4.6cm]{D:/Documents/Pictures/logo.jpg}

\begin{center}
\resizebox{!}{.9cm} {General Rig Description}

\vspace{.5cm}
\Huge Superduper Land Rigs:\\
            Rig 291

\includegraphics[width=7cm]{D:/Documents/Pictures/rig.JPG}  

\textsc{Written By}\\
\huge
{Name Name}
\end{center}

\vspace {.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
            \flushleft
            \Large
            \textsc{Important title}\\
            Name Name
        \end{minipage}
\hfill
        \begin{minipage}[t]{7cm}
            \flushright
            \Large
            \textsc{Important title}\\
            Name Name
        \end{minipage}
    \end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

There is no need to use the `figure` environment  on a title page.

[image]